# after mercurial versioning the "make" fails after calling "./missing ..."

Tags: mercurial, makefile, alsa

I successfully compile alsa-lib when I run `./configure` and subsequently `make` from the sources extracted from the original `.tar.gz`

Since I versioned with mercurial and then try to hg clone the full source tree, the `./configure` and `make` doesn't work anymore.

I compared the `.tar.gz` extracted sources with the hg cloned sources using kdiff3 and they're exactly the same (except for the .hg folder).

What I notice is that running make from the extracted `.tar.gz` it simply compiles; running the same from the hg cloned sources instead, before compiling, calls

```
alsa-lib-1.0.24.1/missing --run aclocal-1.11 -I m4
....
```

then there's again a list of configuration commands before starting the compilation that fails.

deleting all the content of the file named "missing" I can have a successful compilation also from the hg cloned sources but this solution seems to me ugly, does anybody know what's happening here?